# How to split backup file using `pg_dump.exe` in windows

Tags: postgresql

I have tried following command to split backup file but it is always showing error `illegal option split`:

```
pg_dump.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U
postgres --inserts | split -b 2m – backup.sql -f "D:\post\filename.sql" 
db_name
```

Comment: Split is not a command in Windows (although I guess you can use it in Cygwin). Why are you trying to split the dump?

Comment: @harmic: Because I have too much data in database.

Comment: Too much to fit into available disk space, or? Split by itself will not help with that, the sum of the individual files will be the same as the total

Comment: @harmic: Do you have any other way to backup large database in windows machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use pipe (`|`) and unix [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)) command as argument to pg_dump.exe. It won't work. Consider trying [7zip](http://informationworker.ru/7zip.en/cmdline/switches/volume.htm) volumes for that. Or any other command line splitter

Comment: Do you have any other way to achieve this in windows?

Comment: @Code-Monk here is an example: https://techfranz.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/splitting-large-files-using-7-zip-command-line-for-skydrive-2/ how to use 7zip for splitting in commandline